# how do I perform exponentiation of a variable in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Sorry if the question is trivial, but I'm totally newbie in pine. How do I perform exponentiation of a variable in pine script? (in R language I use the ^ operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `math.pow()` for mathematical power function or `math.exp()` when you need to calculate `e` raised to the power of given number.